# searching in 2d array as O(n) with unsorted rows

Tags: java, arrays, search, time-complexity

I need to write a method that takes 2d array 'int [][] m' and a value 'val' and check if val is in the array **in the complexity of O(n) while n defined as the number of rows and m must be squared**

The array that can use as a parameter for my method must return true for this method:

(if it returns true so the array is as requested)

```
public static boolean test(int[][] m) {
    int n = m.length;
    for (int r = 0; r < (n - 1); r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                if (m[r][c] > m[r + 1][i]) return false;
    return true;
}
```

This array returns TRUE:

```
int [][] arr3 = new int [][]{
    { 0,   2,    1,    2,   0,  5,   5,   5,  },
    { 21,  21,   7,    7,   7,  21,  21,  21 ,},
    { 21,  21,  21,   21,  21,  21,  21 , 21, },
    { 21,  21,  23 ,  42,  41,  23,  21,  21, },
    { 60  ,56,  57,   58,  53,  52,  47,  51 ,},
    { 61,  65,  70 ,  72,  73,  78,  82,  98 ,},
    { 112, 121, 112, 134, 123, 100,  98,  111,},
    { 136, 136, 136, 134, 147, 150,  154, 134,},
};
```

My method should return true if `val` is in the array and looks like this:

```
public boolean findValTest(int [][] m, int val){...}
```

Comment: How is `n` defined?

Comment: Oh sorry, added it :) @Turing85

Comment: ... and *O(n)* is supposed to be the worst-case execution time? If so, I have a feeling that this is not possible.

Comment: Where is your `val`?

Comment: there is no 'val' , you choose the val to check if it's inside the array.
O(n) suppose to be worst case :(

Comment: If N is defined as the number of rows, 1 more N adds M more values to check, where M is the number of elements in the row. I'd think you could make this O(M log N) but not O(N). If N is defined as the number of values, then 1 more N adds 1 more value to check, so it would be O(N), at least thats how it seems to me.

Comment: At first glance, each column is sorted, so you could get a O(log n) per column, then multiply that by the number of columns to get O(n log n). But as far as getting O(n)? I'd be interested in reading others' thoughts

Comment: @Otomatonium yep that's what i thought .. idk what to do..

Comment: i think O(n²) is best you can do. You have to check each column, and if the column is correct these have to be n checks. Maybe some very cheesy algorithm can break it down, but I don't think so...

Comment: @DánielSomogyi the problem is.. it's a university assignment and it's not supposed to be that hard!

Comment: Huh I think there is indeed a linear time algorithm. You need to generate two candidate-rows and then only check those two.

Comment: @Turing85 can you code it? :)

Comment: Inspired by @Turing85 's comment, compare val to the max of each column to find what row val has to be in, then do a linear search on that row. Finding max I assume is O(1). Finding the row is O(log n). Finding the value inside the row is O(n), so it's O(1*n + log n + n) -> O(2n + log n) -> O(n). Does that sound like sound reasoning? Open to feedback.

Comment: @Otomatonium How does finding the max of each column help? The max will always be in the last row.

Comment: @17slim Oops my mistake I meant max of each row. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Please be more careful when editing. You removed the squareness constraint in one of your revisions. Also, your constraint checker doesn't test squareness.

Comment: @MatanCohen Yes. See my answer. You removed the constraint that `m` must be square. I assume by accient? If `m` is not square, I am able to construct example matrices that pass your `test(...)` but do not satisfy your formally mentioned condition 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible iff. the matrix `m` is a square matrix of size *n x n*. Core idea is inspired by [oleg.cherednik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50649148/4216641). As soon as we find a `row` in `m`, such that `m[row][0] >= val`, we know that `val` must be in either row `row` or `row - 1`(since the same comparison on `row - 1` was `false`). Thus, we have to find our candidate rows (*O(n)*) and then analyze only those two rows (also *O(n)*). If `m` is not square, but rectangular, the algorithm has a complexity of *O(n + k)*, where *n* is the number of rows and *k* is the number of colums in `m`. This leads to the following algorithm.

```
public class Test {

  public static boolean contains(final int[][]m, final int value) {
    int candidateRow = m.length;
    for (int row = 1; row < m.length; ++row) {
      if (m[row][0] == value) {
        return true;
      }
      if (m[row][0] > value) {
        candidateRow = row;
        break;
      }
    }

    for (int val : m[candidateRow - 1]) {
      if (val == value) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    if (candidateRow < m.length) {
      for (int val : m[candidateRow]) {
        if (val == value) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][] testArray = new int [][]{
        {   0,   2,   1,   2,   0,   5,   5,   5 },
        {  21,  21,   7,   7,   7,  21,  21,  21 },
        {  21,  21,  21,  21,  21,  21,  21,  21 },
        {  21,  21,  23,  42,  41,  23,  21,  21 },
        {  60,  56,  57,  58,  53,  52,  47,  51 },
        {  61,  65,  70,  72,  73,  78,  82,  98 },
        { 112, 121, 112, 134, 123, 100,  98, 111 },
        { 136, 136, 136, 134, 147, 150, 154, 134 }
    };
    for (int[] row : testArray) {
      for (int val : row) {
        System.out.print(contains(testArray, val) + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();

    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    final int[] notInMatrix = { -1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 22, 30, 59, 71, 113, 135 };
    for (int val : notInMatrix) {
      System.out.print(contains(testArray, val) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

We can improve the acutal runtime by determining the candidate lines through a binary search algorithm so that candidate lines are found in *O(log(n))* instead of *O(n)*. The asymptotical runtime will still be *O(n)* for square matrices and *O(log(n) + k)* for non-square *n x k* matrices. The idea for this was taken from [Saeed Bolhasani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50649824/4216641).

```
  private static int findCandidateRow(final int[][] m, final int value) {
    int lower = 0;
    int upper = m.length;
    int middle = (upper + 1) / 2;
    while (middle != m.length 
        && middle != 1
        && (m[middle][0] < value || m[middle - 1][0] > value)) {
      if (m[middle][0] < value) {
        lower = middle;
      } else {
        upper = middle;
      }
      middle = lower + (upper - lower + 1) / 2;
    }
    return middle;
  }
```

Comment: Can I ask why you increasing everytime ++row and not row++ ?

Comment: @MatanCohen it is a personal style thing. for me `++i` is the "more obvious operation" (increment first, return incremented value). Thus, I use preincrement as default and postincrement only when necessary.

Comment: May I ask the downvoter for the reason(s) that lead to the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Smth. like that. In case of *Every number at row `i` is equals or smaller then every number on row `i+1`*, than you can check only first element in each row to define a row, where required value could be. Element in unsorted row can be found only with full scan.

This algorithm have to *scan 2 full rows* only, which is ***O(n)* where *n - number of rows***.

```
public static boolean findValTest(int[][] m, int val) {
    for (int row = 0; row < m.length; row++) {
        if (m[row][0] <= val && row != m.length - 1)
            continue;

        int r = row;

        while (r >= row - 1 && r >= 0) {
            for (int col = 0; col < m[r].length; col++)
                if (m[r][col] == val)
                    return true;

            r--;
        }

        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Test cases:

```
System.out.println(findValTest(arr3, -1)); // false
System.out.println(findValTest(arr3, 5)); // true
System.out.println(findValTest(arr3, 7)); // true
System.out.println(findValTest(arr3, 55)); // false
System.out.println(findValTest(arr3, 47)); // true
System.out.println(findValTest(arr3, 147)); // true
System.out.println(findValTest(arr3, 200)); // false
System.out.println(findValTest(new int[][] { { 3, 4, 5 } }, 4));   // true
```

Comment: rows unsorted unfortunately

Comment: Yes, but `Every number at row 'i' is equals or smaller then every number on row 'i+1`

Comment: this algorithm does not return the correct value for this minimal scenario of `val=4, {{3,4,5}}` either

Comment: @oleg.cherednik you can check the method "test" and see which arrays return true, on those arrays I need to use my method and those arrays only.

Comment: edited the question so it will be more understandable

Comment: I have modified the implementation. You can check it on your test cases. The entire *algoithm* is correct.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik not working good actually.. trying to find 7 and returns 21 on my tester..

Comment: i don't get the 3rd if. You start and row 0 and by 1 each round. why should you go back at any time?

Answer (score 1):

your solution is here. i made a function that do binary search for first column. if the val find in the first column the function return true, else last period of 'l' and 'r' are benefit for us. 'r' and 'l' are always equal of have only one distance(r=l or abs(r-l)=1 ). lower bound of 'r' and 'l' are expected row that the val maybe exist in it. so we should search this row.
O(n) for binary search is Log(n) and for row search is  n. so the final O(n) will be n.code is here:

```
static boolean binarySearch(int arr[][], int l, int r, int x)
{
    if (r>=l)
    {
        int mid = l + (r - l)/2;

        // If the element is present at the 
        // middle itself
        if (arr[mid][0] == x)
           return true;

        // If element is smaller than mid, then 
        // it can only be present in left subarray
        if (arr[mid][0] > x)
           return binarySearch(arr, l, mid-1, x);

        // Else the element can only be present
        // in right subarray
        return binarySearch(arr, mid+1, r, x);
    }

    // We reach here when element is not present
    //  in array

    int row = Math.min(l,r);
    for(int i=0; i<arr[0].length ;i++)
      if(arr[row][i]==x)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```